# Getting 2020 unemployment numbers using blsAPI in R? [code and image included]

Tags: r, api

I am trying to pull 2020 unemployment numbers from the blsAPI in R. I am currently replicating this example from this [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/blsAPI/readme/README.html). I changed the end year to 2020 but I am still getting only the unemployment numbers through 2016 as the latest year.

See image [image]

Here is the code

```
   #Install needed libraries 
install.packages('rjson')
library(rjson)
install.packages('blsAPI')
library(blsAPI)
library(ggplot2)

## Pull the data via the API
payload <- list(
  'seriesid'=c('LAUCN360610000000004', 'LAUCN360610000000006'),
  'startyear'=2007,
  'endyear'=2020)
response <- blsAPI(payload, 2)
json <- fromJSON(response)

## Process results
apiDF <- function(data){
  df <- data.frame(year=character(),
                   period=character(),
                   periodName=character(),
                   value=character(),
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  i <- 0
  for(d in data){
    i <- i + 1
    df[i,] <- unlist(d)
  }
  return(df)
}
View(apiDF)

unemployed.df <- apiDF(json$Results$series[[1]]$data)
labor.force.df <- apiDF(json$Results$series[[2]]$data)

## Change value type from character to numeric
unemployed.df[,4] <- as.numeric(unemployed.df[,4])
labor.force.df[,4] <- as.numeric(labor.force.df[,4])

## Rename value prior to merging
names(unemployed.df)[4] <- 'unemployed'
names(labor.force.df)[4] <- 'labor.force'

## Merge data frames
df <- merge(unemployed.df, labor.force.df)

## Create date and unemployement rate
df$unemployment.rate <- df$unemployed / df$labor.force
df$date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste0('1',df$periodName,df$year), '%d%B%Y'))


## Beginning and end dates for the Great Recession (used in shaded area)
gr.start <- as.POSIXct(strptime('1December2007', '%d%B%Y'))
gr.end <- as.POSIXct(strptime('1June2009', '%d%B%Y'))

View(df)
##Plot out the data
ggplot(df) + geom_rect(aes(xmin = gr.start, xmax = gr.end, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), alpha = 0.4, fill="#DDDDDD") + geom_line(aes(date, unemployment.rate*100)) + ylab('Percent of labor force')  + xlab('Great Recession shaded in gray') + ggtitle('Unemployment Rate for Manhattan, NY (Jan 2007 to Dec 2010)') + theme_bw()

MichiganData <- blsQCEW('Area', year='2017', quarter='1', area='26000')
View(MichiganData)
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be two versions of the package available (version 1 and version 2), which one are you using?

There is a Years per Query limit of 10 years for version 1.

Given that your start date is 2007 and the latest year you are getting is 2016, its likely that you are on version 1.

See API Basics at the link you gave above

Answer (score 0):

As [@Jamie_B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13174162/jamie-b) stated, there are two versions of the BLS API (1.0 and 2.0); the latter requires you to register and obtain an api key that you can then use to query much more efficiently. Your problem may stem from that, but for quality assurance checks, I recommend using a wrapper api called [blscrapeR](https://github.com/keberwein/blscrapeR) that functions very similarly to the original BLS development project.

I've not had many issues leveraging both within the same project environment using R since both packages have unique functions.